# How can I programmatically disable the 'Open File' Security Warning?

Tags: c#, process

I'm creating a gameserver control program- the main functionality of this program is to act on changes within a database, for example start and stop a gameserver's process:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = fArgs;
p.StartInfo.FileName = fName;
p.Start();
```

The problem that I have is that Windows displays a security alert and asks me if I want to run the program:

[image]

This is an issue because I intend for the system to run on Windows Server Core (i.e, no GUI) and so won't be able to act on these warnings (and as clients will be able to create brand new gameservers that the specific server machine hasn't seen before).

Is it possible to bypass this warning via the code, or some other means? Bear in mind that I don't want to [disable the security warning entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703031/2422013) (so that any other programs which are unauthorised are blocked), so the answer (linked above) in [this question doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14702733/2422013) (and this question is a different scenario, hence why it's not a duplicate).

As above, all I can find on this is that I disable the warning via Group Policy, but as I mentioned above I want to avoid this if possible and want to disable the warning for just that process or file name.

Comment: Did you try using a CA-issued code signing certificate to sign your application and its modules?

Comment: cybermonkey Did you solve it ?